# Call a mysql stored procedure from select statement

Tags: mysql

Can we call a MY-Sql procedure from select statement:

Suppose I do have the below procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getStartDate;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure getStartDate(
    in week INT,
    in month varchar(30),
    in yearVal varchar(30), 
    out startDate DATE)
begin 

DECLARE beginDate DATE;

SET beginDate = CONCAT(yearVal, '-', month, '-01');

SET startDate = beginDate;

SELECT startDate;

END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

And I want to call the same from an sql statement like

```
select * from emp where start_date > (call getStartDate(2,'01','2018',@startDate))
```

Is it possible. As I do have a requirement like based on week, month & year I have to fetch the start date and end date. For this I am planning to make to make two procedures which will return start and end date For week I am having data like 1, 2... For month: 01, 02... For year 2017,2018..

Please help a way out as I dont want to loop through the queries and I cannot change the structure as it is an existing live project.

Comment: No can't be done.. Procedure needs to be called with CALL statement.. CALL statement is illegal within a SELECT query

Comment: You could do this sort of thing with a stored function.